# What's the difference between "method" and "fashion" when they both mean the ways you doing something?

Tags: differences

In the dictionary,"fashion" means that if you do something in a particular fashion or after a particular fashion, you do it in that way.So what's the special for "fashion"?

Comment: They are used in widely different senses in different contexts. If dictionary definitions are not helpful, see usage examples. Try substituting one for the other in the examples and search again. Try also to understand the importance of collocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "method" implies that there are somewhat well defined steps that are taken in order to do something. The phrase "in that fashion" doesn't imply specific steps really, and is more ambiguous.

In Java computer programming, for example - despite this being a trivial example - a series of stepwise calculations to be performed is called a "method". You would say something like "Pass the value of 2.5 into the method 'Math.round'". To substitute the word "method" with "fashion" in this context would sound really odd.

Apart from all of that, the word method cannot be used as a verb, but fashion can. That's a significant difference.

Comment: If the asker is not a programmer or a techie, he won't bother reading your example. Please cite more general example. You are not in Stack Overflow.

Comment: As per your advice I reread my post and deemed it to be fabulous just the way it is.

Comment: Actually I can understand your answer because I program, too. I just hope the asker understands it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Their definitions are quite similar but not very the same. Method involves plan, and is therefore in an orderly fashion. Fashion is only the manner or mode but does not include logical order.

**[Method](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/method?s=t)** - a manner or mode of procedure, especially an orderly, logical, or systematic way of instruction, inquiry, investigation, experiment, presentation, etc.

**[Fashion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fashion?s=t)** - manner; way; mode